# How to change nested loops to recursion

Tags: python, loops, recursion

Can someone help me simplify the code? I want to read specific content inside the XML, but I don't know how many layers there are in the file. All I can do is keep adding loops to the nested code.

```
pn=[]
tooling=[]
up=[]
step=[]
dept=[]
layer=[]
for item in document.iterfind('CustomerPart'):
    for st in item.find('Route').find('Steps'):
        pn.append(item.findtext('CustPartNumber'))
        tooling.append(item.find('PartParameters').findtext('Value27'))
        up.append(item.findtext('UnitPerPanel'))
        step.append(st.findtext('StepNo'))
        dept.append(st.findtext('ResourceName'))
        layer.append(item.findtext('TopLevelBomPartNumber'))
    for sub in item.find('SubAssemblies'):
        for st2 in sub.find('Route').find('Steps'):
            pn.append(item.findtext('CustPartNumber'))
            tooling.append(item.find('PartParameters').findtext('Value27'))
            up.append(item.findtext('UnitPerPanel'))
            step.append(st2.findtext('StepNo'))
            dept.append(st2.findtext('ResourceName'))
            layer.append(sub.find('PartParameters').findtext('Value113'))
        try:
            for sub1 in sub.find('SubAssemblies'):
                for st3 in sub1.find('Route').find('Steps'):
                    pn.append(item.findtext('CustPartNumber'))
                    tooling.append(item.find('PartParameters').findtext('Value27'))
                    up.append(item.findtext('UnitPerPanel'))
                    step.append(st3.findtext('StepNo'))
                    dept.append(st3.findtext('ResourceName'))
                    layer.append(sub1.find('PartParameters').findtext('Value113'))
        except :
            continue
                   
df = pd.DataFrame({'PartNumber': pn, 'tooling':tooling,'Unit Per Panel':up, 'step':step,'dept':dept,'layer':layer})
```

Comment: NEVER use `try:...except: continue` (or `except: pass`)! Handle exceptions you expect (`continue` is fine if that's what you want), but NEVER use such a generic exception handler.

Comment: can you please add your xml file

Comment: @AbdulRazak thanks for your reply but the xml file is confidential, so I can't share at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this code, you don't really need a recursion! all you have to do is remove repeated code!

Add a function to do all **repeated appends**, I called this function `append_all()` and the code becomes more clear and simple:

#### code:

```py
pn, tooling, up, step, dept, layer=[], [], [], [], [], []

def append_all(item_sub, st, status):
    for st in item.find('Route').find('Steps'):
        pn.append(item.findtext('CustPartNumber'))
        tooling.append(item.find('PartParameters').findtext('Value27'))
        up.append(item.findtext('UnitPerPanel'))
        step.append(st.findtext('StepNo'))
        dept.append(st.findtext('ResourceName'))
        if status == 'st':
            layer.append(item_sub.findtext('TopLevelBomPartNumber'))
        elif status == 'st2' or status == 'st3':
            layer.append(item_sub.find('PartParameters').findtext('Value113'))

for item in document.iterfind('CustomerPart'):
    append_all(item, st, 'st')
    for sub in item.find('SubAssemblies'):
        append_all(sub, st2, 'st2')
        try:
            for sub1 in sub.find('SubAssemblies'):
                append_all(sub1, st3, 'st3')  
        except :
            continue
                   
df = pd.DataFrame({'PartNumber': pn, 'tooling':tooling,'Unit Per Panel':up, 'step':step,'dept':dept,'layer':layer})
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Using functions solves part of the problem to a certain extent, but my biggest problem is that I don't know how many layers there are in the file. Currently I've only written to layer 3 based on visual observation, there may be layer N. So I hope to solve the hierarchical problem with recursion.